# como posso coloca uma condição em if para que não acontece se o array tiver "..." no final da frase

Tags: php, jquery

como posso coloca uma condição em if(`if (strlen($string) > $size) {`) para que não acontece se o array tiver "..." no final da frase

```
$prod->setNome(Utility::limitaString($prod->getNome(), 30));

    public static function limitaString ($string, $size = 50) {
    if (strlen($string) > $size) {
        $string = substr($string, 0, $size);
        for ($i=$size; $i>=0; $i--) {
            $limiters = array(" ", "\n", "\t");
            if (in_array($string[$i], $limiters)) {
                if ($string[$i-1] == "\r")
                $i = $i-1;
                $string = substr($string, 0, $i);
                $string .= "...";
                return $string;
            }
        }
        $string .= "...";
    }
    return $string;
}
```

Essa função acima é feita para reduzi as frase para 30 caracteres e adiciona "..." no final da frase.
mas eu preciso dessa condição para algumas frase já abreviadas que eu não quero pelo método.

como seria condição para array com no final "...".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a função [substr](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.substr.php) do PHP, para isso basta informar um número negativo.

Verifica o tamanho da variável `string` e verifica se os três últimos caracteres da variável `string` não são os três pontos.

```
if (strlen($string) > $size && substr($string,-3) !== '...')
```

Uma observação a se fazer, é que no exemplo acima, vai verificar se o tamanho da variável `string` é maior do que o valor informado na variável `$size`, se for a condição vai fazer a verificação se a variável `string` não contém os três pontos no final, retornando verdadeiro ( que não contém os três pontos ) ele vai limitar a variável `string`, se conter ele não vai limitar.

Veja funcionando no [ideone](https://ideone.com/gNZIwN)

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que isso deva funcionar:

```
$prod->setNome(Utility::limitaString($prod->getNome(), 30));

    public static function limitaString ($string, $size = 50) {
    if (strlen($string) > $size) {
        $string = substr($string, 0, $size);
        for ($i=$size; $i>=0; $i--) {
            $limiters = array(" ", "\n", "\t");
            if (in_array($string[$i], $limiters)) {
                if ($string[$i-1] == "\r")
                $i = $i-1;
                $string = substr($string, 0, $i);
                if( strstr($string,"...")){
                    //return null
                }else{
                    $string .= "...";
                }
                return $string;
            }
        }
        if( strstr($string,"...")){
             //return null
        }else{
             $string .= "...";
        }
    }
    return $string;
}
```

Obs: não testei.

Answer (score 2):

Não entendi muito bem essa do array, mas vou fazer o que entendi:

```
preg_match(".{3}$", $string, $ultimos3);
if ($ultimos3[0] != "..." && strlen($string) > $size)
```

Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/z04XGa).

**O que eu fiz:**

Na primeira linha, utilizei uma expressão regular([regex](/questions/tagged/regex)) para pegar os 3 últimos caracteres.

Na segunda, é o mesmo `if` que você estava usando, porem agora ele verifica se o regex retornou `...`.

**Referencias:**

- Função
  [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-match.php) na
  documentação oficial do php.

Answer (score 2):

Tenta isso:

```
if (!stripos($string, "...") {
   //se ela achar as retiscencias ela não executa
   //seu codigo AQUI
}
```

O que ela irá fazer é, procurar na sua variável `string` se existe em alguma parte o texto "...", caso não ache, ele irá executar o seu código. Ele busca em toda a `$string` ignorando a posição, buscando apenas encontrar o que foi pedido. Acho que isso pode resolver o seu problema.

[Link](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.stripos.php) para a função do PHP.
Boa sorte!